# Indexing H4 and H5 heading as parent and child from content

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the how my content looks like :

```
$content ='<h4>Pros of personal loans</h4>
<h5>Consolidation for your</h5>
<p>credit cards and other debts. A personal loan can be used</p>
<h5>Can you afford it?</h5>
<p>Improved credit score. You may improve your credit score by moving</p>
<h4>Cons of personal loans</h4>
<p>Higher interest rates than secured loans and (some) credit cards.</p>
<p>Extended application process.</p>
<h4>Is a personal loan right for you?</h4>
<p>Personal loans work best as part of a</p>
<h4>test</h4>
<p>Personal loans work best as part of a</p> 
<h5>test1</h5>
<p>Personal loans work best as part of a</p>';
```

This is how i want it to be :

```
<h4>Pros of personal loans</h4>
--<h5>Consolidation for your</h5>
--<h5>Can you afford it?</h5>
<h4>Cons of personal loans</h4>
<h4>Is a personal loan right for you?</h4>    
<h4>test</h4>   
--<h5>test1</h5>
```

Here is the design what i am trying to do : http://screencast.com/t/lN3HtBYjEWUA

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `$("h5").css({"margin-left":"10px"});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move h5 tags inside h4 as follows:

```
$content ='<h4>Pros of personal loans
              <h5>Consolidation for your</h5>
              <p>credit cards and other debts. A personal loan can be used</p>
              <h5>Can you afford it?</h5>
           </h4>.................'
```

Comment: thanks for your message .  I am trying to indexing it , please take a look at at image link for batter understanding  , so once user will click on it , it will scroll up to the title .